# How can I hide irrelevant contacts in Go Contacts?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, contacts, sync, go-contacts

When I was using stock contacts and sync with Google, I could put relevant contacts in *My Contacts* group which is the only group synced by Google. I have installed GO Contacts and it now displays all groups except *My Contacts*.

What I want to do is to group irrelevant contacts somehow and hide them from my phone contacts or ignore them in sync. Please note that I do not want to mess with *My Contacts* group in case I decided to go back to stock Contacts.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will answer your question, but there is a Settings (button) called "Contacts Account" which lets you show or hide the following contacts:
- Phone
- Google
- SIM
- Facebook
- Twitter
- Show contacts with phone numbers only

Comment: I want to show all these and but I want to only sync selected groups from the ones I defined in Google Contacts.

Comment: Where's the problem? Items from "Phone" and "SIM" will never be synced -- so you could place all your "ignore-me" items there. Provided you can change them accordingly...